# Series with exponential growth rate, ratio test is subordinate to the root test.

Tags: real-analysis

(a) Show that if a series has ratio lim sup $\rho$ then it has exponential growth rate $\rho$. Infer that the ratio test is subordinate to the root test.

I will be honest; I have no idea how to start this. What is $\rho$? What does "subordinate" mean. These were not mentioned in class and I'm having so much hard time. This is a homework question so if you don't want to answer, a hint will be okay. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

We are talking about convergence tests for series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$.
The root test investigates $\limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{a_k}$, the ratio test $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|$.
Now a better formulation of the problem at hand might be:

> Assume $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=\rho$. Then show that $|a_k|\le c\rho^k$ for some $c$.
>   Infer that the ratio test cannot be better than the root test.